# Monitor progress of ZIP file extraction

Tags: import, compression

Importing a ZIP file containing potentially many individual files in a (custom) format using

```
Import[filename, {{"*"}, "Gaussian"}]
```

takes quite a while. How can I monitor the progress of this operation without compromising efficiency?

I tried

```
raw = Import[filename, {{"*"}, "String"}];
Map[ImportString[#, "Gaussian"] &, raw]
```

but this is ca 80% slower.

[2014-10-16 16:00] Here is a toy example for demonstration purposes:

```
Test`TestImportDefault[input_] := (Pause[0.01]; "result")
ImportExport`RegisterImport["test", Test`TestImportDefault];

zips = ExportString[Table[RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 1000], {500}], 
    {"ZIP", Table[{IntegerString[i], "String"}, {i, 500}]}];

AbsoluteTiming[ImportString[zips, {"ZIP", {"*"}, "test"}];][[1]]
AbsoluteTiming[t = ImportString[zips, {"ZIP", {"*"}, "String"}]; 
    Map[ImportString[#, "test"] &, t]][[1]]
```

yielding 14s and 18s, respectively, on my laptop.

Comment: Can you provide a file so we can try things?

Comment: @Öskå: I can, but it's too much import code and too large files than fit on the question page itself. I added a toy example that demonstrates the problem in principle: It is easy to add a progress bar to the second approach, but it's too slow compared to the first one.

Comment: It may prove faster to gin up the system call to use an external utility to unzip to a scratch directory, then import the individual files (Of course then you could readily monitor the individual file progress )

Comment: @george2079: Thanks, works for me, yielding about equal performance. I had expected this to be much slower due to duplication of disk IO, but apparently it's not. Solid state drive might have helped, too.